# How to display images from sdcard smoothly in android

Tags: java, android, sd-card

The below code is downloading images from a database showing into an sdcard. When previewing it was showing images. The first image showed perfectly, but from next image onwards it was showing like blank and loading images from the sdcard, but from sdcard it was not downloading image directly displaying images.

**java**

```
public class ImageGallery extends Activity {

    Bundle bundle;
    String catid, temp, responseJson;
    JSONObject json;
    ImageView imageViewPager;
    // for parsing
    JSONObject o1, o2;
    JSONArray a1, a2;
    int k;
    Boolean toggleTopBar;
    ArrayList<String> imageThumbnails;
    ArrayList<String> imageFull;
    public static int imagePosition=0;
    SubsamplingScaleImageView imageView, imageViewPreview, fullImage ;
    ImageView thumb1,  back;
    private  LinearLayout thumb2;
    RelativeLayout topLayout, stripeView;
    RelativeLayout thumbnailButtons;
    FrameLayout gridFrame;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader;
    //SharedPreferences data
    SharedPreferences s1;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    int swipeCounter;
    ParsingForFinalImages parsingObject;
int position_grid;
    SharedPreferences p;

    Bitmap bm;
    int numOfImagesInsidee;
    LinearLayout backLinLayout;
    public static boolean isThumb2=false;
    public static boolean isThumb1=false;

public static ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_gallery);
        //isThumb2=false;
        toggleTopBar = false;
        //position_grid=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("position");


        thumbnailButtons = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.thumbnailButtons);
        topLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.topLayout);
        //fullImage = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.fullimage);

        backLinLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.lin_back);
        backLinLayout.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent io = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        // clear the previous activity and start a new task
                        // System.gc();
                        // io.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(io);
                        finish();

                    }

                });

        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(getBaseContext());
        Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();



        thumb1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumb1);
        thumb2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.thumb2);
        stripeView = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.stripeView) ;
        gridFrame = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridFrame);


        thumb1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        stripeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        gridFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //fullImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        thumb1.setClickable(false);
                        isThumb1=true;
isThumb2=false;
                        Log.i("Thumb Position 1",""+ImageGallery.imagePosition);
                        viewPager.removeAllViews();
                        Fragment newFragment = new GridFragment2();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.gridFrame, newFragment).commit();


                    }

                });
        thumb2.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {


                        // stripeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        stripeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        gridFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       // fullImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        thumb1.setClickable(true);
                        isThumb2=true;
                        isThumb1=false;
                        Log.i("Thumb Position 2",""+ImageGallery.imagePosition);
                        viewPager.removeAllViews();
                        Fragment newFragment = new ImageStripeFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.gridFrame, newFragment).commit();

                    }
                });




        // allow networking on main thread
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        /*bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        catid = bundle.getString("catid");*/
        // Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), catid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        // making json using the catalogue id we got

        p = getSharedPreferences("gridData", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        catid = p.getString("SelectedCatalogueIdFromGrid1", "");
        int clickedListPos = p.getInt("clickedPosition", 0);



        imageViewPreview = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        imageThumbnails = new ArrayList<String>();
        imageFull = new ArrayList<String>();
        s1 = this.getSharedPreferences("data", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        editor = s1.edit();


        Log.d("catidfnl", catid);
        numOfImagesInsidee = p.getInt("numberOfItemsSelectedFromGrid1", 0);

        Log.d("blingbling2", String.valueOf(numOfImagesInsidee));

        // adding downloaded images to arraylist
        for(int m=0;m<numOfImagesInsidee;m++){
            imageThumbnails.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"thumbImage" + catid + m+".png");
            imageFull.add(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"fullImage" + catid + m+".png");


            // imageFull.add("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "fullImage32.png");

        }

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);













        // code to display image in a horizontal strip starts here
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        for (int i = 0; i < imageThumbnails.size(); i++) {
            imageView = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(this);
            imageView.setId(i);

            imageView.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

            // Picasso.with(this).load("file://"+imageThumbnails.get(i)).into(imageView);

            // imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            layout.addView(imageView);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = imageView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = 200;
            params.height = 200;
            imageView.setLayoutParams(params);

            imageView.setZoomEnabled(false);
            imageView.setDoubleTapZoomScale(0);

            imageView.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageThumbnails.get(0)));

            imageView.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {



                            imageView.setZoomEnabled(false);
                            imageViewPreview.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(view.getId())));
                            imageView.recycle();
                            imageViewPreview.recycle();

                        }
                    });
        }
        // code to display image in a horizontal strip ends here

        imageViewPreview.setZoomEnabled(false);

        /*imageViewPreview.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        imageViewPreview.setZoomEnabled(false);
                        stripeView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        gridFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });*/

        imageViewPreview.setOnClickListener(new DoubleClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                 Log.d("yo click", "single");
            }

            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick(View v) {
                Log.d("yo click", "double");
            }
        });


    }


    public abstract class DoubleClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA = 300;//milliseconds

        long lastClickTime = 0;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long clickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (clickTime - lastClickTime < DOUBLE_CLICK_TIME_DELTA){
                onDoubleClick(v);
            } else {
                onSingleClick(v);
            }
            lastClickTime = clickTime;
        }

        public abstract void onSingleClick(View v);
        public abstract void onDoubleClick(View v);
    }




//    @Override
//    public void onBackPressed() {
//        Intent io = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
//        // clear the previous activity and start a new task
//        super.onBackPressed();
//        finish();
//        // System.gc();
//        // io.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
//        startActivity(io);
//    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_image_gallery, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
       /* private int[] mImages = new int[] {
                R.drawable.scroll3,
                R.drawable.scroll1,
                R.drawable.scroll2,
                R.drawable.scroll4

        };*/
        /* private String[] description=new String[]
                 {
                    "One","two","three","four"
                 };
 */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            Log.i("Image List Size", "" + imageFull.size());
            return imageFull.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);
        }




        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = ImageGallery.this;

           // ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(context, 1);
           // loader.DisplayImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(imagePosition)),imageView,imagePosition,new ProgressDialog(context));
            SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);

            // for placeholder
            // fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.resource(R.drawable.tan2x));

            if(!GridFragment2.isSelectedGrid2&&!ImageStripeFragment.isImageStripe) {
            imagePosition = position;
            fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(imagePosition)));

        }
       /* else if(!ImageStripeFragment.isImageStripe)
        {
            imagePosition = position;
            fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(imagePosition)));
        }
        else if(ImageStripeFragment.isImageStripe)
        {
            position=imagePosition;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(imagePosition);
            fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position)));
        }*/
            else
        {
            position=imagePosition;
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(imagePosition);
            fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position)));


            //viewPager.removeAllViews();

        }

          // ImageView  imageViewPager = new ImageView(context);
           // ImageView imageViewPager = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
           // SubsamplingScaleImageView fullImage = new SubsamplingScaleImageView(ImageGallery.this);

            GridFragment2.isSelectedGrid2=false;
            ImageStripeFragment.isImageStripe=false;

           // Log.i("Image Resource", "" + ImageSource.uri(imageFull.get(position)));
        // imageViewPager.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFull.get(position)));
       // imageViewPager.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

            // fullImage.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bmImg));

            //imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imageFull.get(position)));
          /*int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
              R.dimen.padding_medium);
          imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);*/
            /*imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(imageFull.get(position)));

            if(position==3)
            {

            }*/
            //  Log.i("Image Position",""+position);
          /*text.setText(description[position]);
          Log.i("Text Position",""+position);*/
          /*switch(position)
          {

          case 0:
              String pos=String.valueOf(position);
            text.setText(pos);

              break;
          case 1:
              String pos1=String.valueOf(position);
              text.setText(pos1);
              break;
          case 2:
              String pos2=String.valueOf(position);
              text.setText(pos2);
              break;
          case 3:
              String pos3=String.valueOf(position);
              text.setText(pos3);
              break;
          }*/



            fullImage.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {

                            if (toggleTopBar == false) {
                                // thumbnailButtons.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                thumbnailButtons.animate()
                                        .translationY(-2000)
                                        .setDuration(1000)
                                        .start();
                                toggleTopBar = true;
                            } else if (toggleTopBar == true) {
                                // thumbnailButtons.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                thumbnailButtons.animate()
                                        .translationY(0)
                                        .setDuration(1000)
                                        .start();
                                toggleTopBar = false;
                            }

                        }
                    });
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(fullImage, 0);

            return fullImage;
        }

       @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((SubsamplingScaleImageView) object);
        }
       /* @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object o) {
            Log.d("DESTROY", "destroying view at position " + position);
            View view = (View) o;
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView(view);
            view = null;
        }*/


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onBackPressed();

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be the best approach for your Solution,Try using Universal Image Loader.

**Features:**

- Multithread image loading (async or sync)
- Wide customization of ImageLoader's configuration (thread executors, downloader, decoder, memory and disk cache, display image options, etc.)
- Many customization options for every display image call (stub images, caching switch, decoding options, Bitmap processing and displaying, etc.)
- Image caching in memory and/or on disk (device's file system or SD card)
  Listening loading process (including downloading progress)

Find link here : **https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader**